# Load only 10000 records from file with 200000 records in Talend

Tags: talend

I have a CSV file with around 200.000 records. I need to load data in DB which is in SQL Server.

I only need to load 10000 records in the DB and not all. How can it be achieved in Talend?

Comment: If the load is on basis of duplicate records, you can use tUniqRow

Comment: If you use tFileInputDelimited as input component, then you can find limit option in component tab, then you can give any number u want to process the records....hope it is helpful

Comment: you may also use tSampleRow component